# Where to add the code for an outer container in a theme?

Tags: theme-options, id, css

I have a Wordpress theme installed (SimplePress) and I would like to add an outer container to it, and I don't know exactly in which file should I add the code.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
<div id="hbz_outer_container" style="position: relative;">
<div id="hbz_drop_shadow">
```

This is an example of how I would like it to look: http://www.harpersbazaar.com

I tried adding the code to some of the files, like `scripts.php` or other files from the theme, but I don't know if I have to change a file from the theme, or a file from WordPress.

Comment: Try `header.php` and `footer.php` in your theme directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really hard to say without being able to look at your theme files directly. But you are most likely going to have to put

```
<div id="hbz_outer_container" style="position: relative;">
<div id="hbz_drop_shadow">
```

somewhere in your header.php and then put the closing tags:

```
</div><!-- hbz_drop_shadow -->
</div><!-- hbz_outer_container -->
```

in your footer.php

header.php and footer.php should be located in your wordpress installed themes folder.

ie:

yoursite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/header.php

and

yoursite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/footer.php

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, this worked perfectly! (i don't know why someone downvoted the question... i tried to make myself clear)

Comment: Don't swet it :), but they probably down voted because it was a pretty basic question that barely related to wordpress, other than needing to know what files to edit. But you don't know unless you ask, so keep asking :)